# Search multiple values if present

Tags: php, sql

sorry my English is weak ....
how can i search multi values from db SQL So that there was any.
i can search name && family together but 
I want when the user searched name And family leave empty Return result correctly
how can i write this

```
if (isset($_POST['searchname']) || isset($_POST['searchfamily'])) {
   $sql = "select * from myinfo WHERE name='{$_POST['searchname']}' && family='{$_POST['searchfamily']}' ORDER BY id DESC";
}
else {
   $sql = "select * from myinfo ORDER BY id DESC";
}
```

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tried?

Comment: `where name like '%jones%' or family like '%jones%'`

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: i edit my question and add my cod

Comment: i dont want use "or" because  If both I want there to be applied both in query

Comment: Are you running Mysqli?

Comment: Yes db is Mysqli and use PDO

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search with both then you need to change your  if also. And change `&&` to `and` in your query

```
if (isset($_POST['searchname']) && isset($_POST['searchfamily'])) {

$sql = "select * from myinfo WHERE `name`='{$_POST['searchname']}' AND family='{$_POST['searchfamily']}' ORDER BY id DESC";
    }
else {

$sql = "select * from myinfo ORDER BY id DESC";

}
```

**Edit**

As per your comment try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['searchname']) || isset($_POST['searchfamily'])) {
  $where="";
  if(isset($_POST['searchname']))
    $where=" WHERE `name`='{$_POST['searchname']}'";
  if(isset($_POST['searchfamily']))
  {
    if($where=="")
      $where=" WHERE family='{$_POST['searchfamily']}'";
    else
      $where=" AND family='{$_POST['searchfamily']}'";
  }
  $sql = "select * from myinfo $where ORDER BY id DESC";
}
else {

  $sql = "select * from myinfo ORDER BY id DESC";

}
```

Comment: You've missed one vital part ;-) `name=`

Comment: I want if search name or search family or both .... work correctly   ... this cod only for when enter nama and family together but i search only name this not work

Answer (score 0):

Your 3 main issues here..

the first being `WHERE name=` now.. `name` is already used by mysql therefore you shouldn't use it however.. If you do use it run it like this:

```
WHERE `name`=
```

You should always backtick database tables and columns to make life easier in the long haul.

The second issue being you used `&&` where it should be `AND`

the third is you shouldn't be placing your variables straight into your query as you're left open for SQL Injection.

Now I'm running on the assumption you're using `$mysqli` as your variable however, this may need adjusting to suit the correct variable you are using:

```
if (isset($_POST['searchname']) || isset($_POST['searchfamily'])) {

    $searchName = $_POST['searchname'];
    $family = $_POST['searchfamily'];

    $sql = $mysqli->prepare("select * from `myinfo` WHERE `name` = ? OR `family`= ? ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    $sql->execute([$searchName, $family]);
} else {

    $sql = $mysqli->prepare("select * from `myinfo` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    $sql->execute();

}
```

Comment: It does not matter with my code . This was only true if the Both enter the last and first names...

Comment: You're asking whats wrong.. We are pointing out what's wrong and you then argue it? Why ask to begin with?

Comment: Therefore change `AND` to `OR` - I've updated this in my example

Comment: If i use "or" when i search name user 1 and search family user 2 .resualt is user 1 and user2 . I dont want this